# Why is this? "error: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: c, macos, makefile, rendering, apple-m1

I was trying to build [this](https://github.com/DonaldJamesJohnson/RD_RenderingEngine.git) Then i get this error

```
$make  
g++ -o rd_view -g -Wall libcs631.a rd_direct.o pnm_display.o -lm -lX11
ld: library not found for -lX11
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [rd_view] Error 1
```

I'm on m1 mac ventura. Any help will be appreciated. I tried installing libx11,Xquartz also.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `libX11.a` in your default library directories.

Locate (or/and install)it.

To install (ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

To search

```
Use apt-file search [filename]
```

Location on my computer:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a
```

As an additional remark: move your `libcs631.a` after all the object files as libraries are are searched only one time so all needed symbols have to be known to the linker before it searches the library.

Comment: Telling someone who's on macOS how to install something on ubuntu isn't going to help them very much...